# uml - Template class diagram with typedef

Tags: class, uml, diagram, class-diagram

I'm trying to create a class diagram starting from my c++ code. I'm having trouble because I can't find standard rules on how to represent what I have in my code. Here's what I have. 
EDIT: extended .h files

```
#ifndef TYPES_H_INCLUDED
#define TYPES_H_INCLUDED

#include <vector>

using namespace std;

//natural numbers
typedef unsigned int N;

//lattice c_no<c_lt,c_gt<c_eq of comparison results in a PO
typedef char CMP;

//intervals [l,u] in R with l<=u, with inclusion order
template <typename R> 
struct IR
{
  R l, u;
  IR() {};
  IR(R,R);
};

//unions of intervals (increasing sequence of disjoint intervals)
template <typename R> 
struct U_IR
{
    vector<IR <R> > S;
    U_IR() {};
};

//points in R^d with d>0, with pointwise order
template <typename R> 
struct PR
{
    vector<R> x;
    PR(N d){ x=vector<R>(d);};
};

//boxes in R^d with d>0, with inclusion order
template <typename R> 
struct BR
{
    vector<IR <R> > x;
    BR(N d){ x=vector<IR <R> >(d);};
};

//U_BR unions of boxes in Number^d, see UBR.h

#include "IR.tpp"
#include "UIR.tpp"
#include "basic.tpp"
#include "BR.tpp"


#endif// TYPES_H_INCLUDED
```

and

```
#ifndef DAG_H_INCLUDED
#define DAG_H_INCLUDED

#include <fstream>
#include "types.h"

using namespace std;

template <typename R>
using Leaf=U_IR<R>; 
//typedef U_IR<R> Leaf;//non-empty leaf in DAG

typedef vector<N> ListN;

template <typename R> 
struct Node//non-empty node in DAG
{
    vector < R > x; //incresing sequence in R of size #x>0
    ListN ux;//sequences of #x links to level below in DAG
    ListN u; //sequences of #x-1 links to level below in DAG
    friend bool operator==(const Node<R>&X1, const Node<R>&X2)
    {
        return X1.x==X2.x &&X1.ux==X2.ux &&X1.u==X2.u;
    };
};

template <typename R>
using Leaves=vector < Leaf<R> >;
//typedef vector < Leaf<R> > Leaves;//set of nodes at level 0 in DAG

template <typename R> 
using Nodes=vector<Node <R> >;
//typedef vector < Node<R> > Nodes;//set of nodes at a given level in DAG

template <typename R> 
class DAG
{
protected:
    Leaves<R> leaf;  //set of non-empty nodes at level 0, G empty if #leaf=0
    vector < Nodes<R> > nodes;//nodes[l] set of non-empty nodes at level l+
    //memoization
    vector<vector <vector <CMP> > > C;
    //C[l][j][i] comparison of i and j at level l, with i<j ('?' if not computed yet)
    vector<vector <vector <N> > > U;
    //U[l][j][i] result of union of i and j  at level l, with i<j (0 if not computed yet)
    N add_leaf(const Leaf<R>&);//prevent duplication
    N add_node(const Node<R>&, N l);//prevent duplication
    bool cover(const BR<R>&,ListN&,N l) const;
    bool cover(R,R,const Node<R>&,ListN&) const;
    CMP cmp(N,N,N l);//comparison of nodes at level l
    void cmp(const Node<R> &, const Node<R> &, CMP &, N l);
    N make(const BR<R>&,N l);//make at level l
    N sum(N,N,N l);//union of nodes at level l
    Node<R> sum(const Node<R> & X1, const Node<R> & X2, N l);
public:
    DAG(N d);//dimension d>0
    void print() const;//print DAG (for debug purposes)
    void print_test(ostream &cout) const;//print for testing
    void print2(N) const;//print subsets of the plane with integer bounds
    N dim() const;
    N empty() const;
    bool cover(const BR<R>&,N) const;
    CMP cmp(N,N);
    N make(const BR<R>&);
    N sum(N,N);
};

#include "DAG.tpp"
#include "DAG-sum.tpp"
#include "DAG-cover.tpp"
#include "DAG-make.tpp"
#include "DAG-cmp.tpp"


#endif  // DAG_H_INCLUDED
```

I don't know how to do in uml the using (same of typedef but with template) part recursively. Can anyone show me the right way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Typedefs are usually represented as special stereotypes since UML 2 standards. The template option either stays with generic parameters, or goes with specification of these.

Comment: So in my case how can I represent a typedef of a typedef? I mean graphically @πάνταῥεῖ

Comment: Might work well, yes. If the graphic representation looks representative for the situation. Cannot tell about code generation would be done correctly. Depends on the tool a bit probably.

Comment: I still own Enterprise Architect, and might try to import your code, and what the tool does with it if you want me to do. (might take some time, since my laptop is a bit lame)

Comment: May be [this](https://www.genmymodel.com/uml) could be helpful to try yourself.

Comment: You would be very kind! Thank you! If you need more code tell me @πάνταῥεῖ. Thank you

Comment: Yeah, sure. Will take a moment as mentioned. I believe the code you've given  is enough, presumed it correctly compiles already.

Comment: yes sure, I just cut it because it is so much longer

Comment: Hmm, I tried to import your code as is from a quickly made header file. No class elements were recognized from EA.

Comment: I probably need a [MCVE] of your code to make EA satisfied. Working instantiations of your template classes, without any compiler errors.

Comment: I edited the post with complete .h files. Do you need also .tpp files for methods source code?

Comment: Yeah, thanks, seems that was enough that EA identified the class declarations. As mentioned you might want to add additional dependency and "meta" relationships to make the diagram more readable.

Comment: There's a dependency relation with the «bind» stereotype to present template parameter bindings in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the UML diagram that's automatically generated by my UML tool:

[image]

I didn't read in deeper about your use case, so you might want to add additional dependency relationships (use proper stereotypes <sup>«use»</sup> / <sup>«bind»</sup> as needed) to clarify some more things for a reader of the diagram.

Comment: thank you very much! but as you can see types defined with using instead of typedef are not mentioned. Probably because of template (I can't template a typedef) I need to use "using" and EA does not recognize that kind of construct. I will describe it like a normal typedef.

Comment: @cristina Yeah sure. I mentioned you might add more relations or intermediate type(def) instantiations to clarify your intends. I generally know the problem because I also tend sometimes to write working code 1st, and document it in UML afterwards. I always need to tune what the UML tools import from the code, to add some additional information a halfway skilled colleague can make sense of.

Comment: He's after the **using namespace std;** which should be an `<<import>>` I guess.